# Не правильно создается первый коммит в удаленной реп

Tags: git, github

Удалил старый репозиторий и создал новый . Создал pom xml checkstyle gitignore README.md
делаю первый инит коммит в в созданной репе появляется такая куча непонятных коммитов до инит коммита а гит статус показывает следующее до первого коммита -

```
 C:\projects\dream_job>git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    ../job4j_dreamjob/.gitignore
        deleted:    ../job4j_dreamjob/README.md
        deleted:    ../job4j_dreamjob/checkstyle.xml
        deleted:    ../job4j_dreamjob/pom.xml
        deleted:    ../job4jdreamjob/.gitignore
        deleted:    ../job4jdreamjob/README.md
        deleted:    ../job4jdreamjob/checkstyle.xml
        deleted:    ../job4jdreamjob/pom.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ./
```

в чем причина того , что показывает старые файлы уже с удаленного реп.???

Comment: как удалил? как создал?

Comment: удалил в гите самом через раздел удаление репозитория , создал пустую репу и в идее создал новы мавен проект и подключил его к репе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по выводу команды `git status` локальный репозиторий вы не удаляли и не пересоздавали, а просто удалили файлы из рабочей копии.

Вы пытаетесь сделать не первый, а очередной коммит в непустой локальной копии

Comment: спасибо точно забыл про локальный репозиторий)